# Does a battery charger limit current?

Tags: battery-charging

I am asking if the battery needs a specific amount of current to charge and I tried to charge it throw a charging circuit (which is designed for the battery), will it limit the current so it will be suitble for the battery ?.
example : lets say that I have a battery that need to charge on 1 amp, if I connect 2 amps to the charging circuit, will it provide only the needing 1 amp ?
also, what will will happen to the 1 amp that gets reduced by the charging circuit ?.

Answer (score 1):

The current for charging a battery is a function of it Amp-Hour capacity (Ahr) and the battery chemistry.  Suppose you have a single 2.2 AHr cell, to the charge that battery in 1 hour, you needed 2.2 A.  We call this a batteries charge rate (C) which a metric for normalizing charging specifications.  In the example above, it was charged at 1C.  If we had two cells were in series, capacity for the pack is still 2.2 Ahr, and can be charged with 1C.  If the cells were in parallel, the capacity is now 4.4 Ahr, and 4.4 A is needed to charge them in 1 hour, but the charge rate is still 1C. You can now see why the charge rate metric was invented.

As for what charge rate to use... you can guesstimate by using other pack charge rates for common devices you use.  For example, a laptop, takes two hour to charge a 12Ahr pack, that is 0.5C, 6A. From this you can guess that its safe to charge this lithium ion pack at this rate rate.

Most batteries prefer constant current charging... However I have seen some lead acid batteries used in UPS systems that can take a constant voltage source.... However, I think everyone can agree that to maximize life of the cells you want to use a constant.

I have a little calculator I wrote that lets you play around with different charge currents, state of charge, and pack capacities.  The link is provided below.

http://onesolver.com/#!service=system_saved_load&id=42&tab=2
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your charging circuit will (ideally) limit the charging current.

The charger typically connects to a voltage source - eg your mains AC (which it converts to the required DC). The input current draw is dictated by the output load (voltage output and current draw of output) and efficiency of the converter.

The charging current will be set by the charger depending on battery chemistry and charge time. This sets charge rate which sets the charging current.